# Can i use Mysql VS code plugin with out Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, vscode-extensions

does mysql workbench needed if i have mysql vscode plugin.

Is it necessary to install mysql workbench if i have mysql vs code plugin?
I realy don't like mysql workbench it gives too much load in my pc i want to avoid installing it if possible so help me

I didnt try anything yet

Comment: You can use any mysql client that you like. vscode plugin - as well

Comment: mysql workbench is just a mysql client. Mysql clients do not have any impact on other mysql clients.

Comment: Is that means yes? I can use only the plugin and not install the workbench?

Comment: yes. mysql is a server. it stores and sends data to clients. 

The mysql workbench is just one of the clients.

Any other mysql client can at least query a mysql server.

Comment: Ty for that and ty for taking time to answer my question appreciate it